# Android Studio - Why WebView Doesn't Load Web URL

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Android Studio - Why WebView Doesn't Load Web URL

[image]
[image]

[image]
-------------------------------My MainActivity.java-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```js
package com.spgisslive;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.spgisslive.R.id.webview;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private WebView mWebView;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);








    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page03, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Page 01";
                case 1:
                    return "Page 02";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I can't speak well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where you are written code to load URL in WebView i haven't seen it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc6fI.png

Comment: I haven't seen any code to load SubPage01 fragment from MainActivity.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3gFtz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load WebView with URL in `onCreateView()` with check first section case from `PlaceholderFragment` as below :

```
if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
    return rootView;
}
```

Another way to achieve using each Fragment class :

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           if(position==0){
              return SubPage01.newInstance(position + 1);
           }else if(position==1){
              return SubPage02.newInstance(position + 1);
           }else{
              return SubPage03.newInstance(position + 1);
           }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Page 01";
                case 1:
                    return "Page 02";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank You It Work.

Comment: @Supagarn Have you create Fragment class for each page ?

Comment: Yes   I create fragment class for each page